# Deriving newtype recursively like functionality

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

Lets say, in package `P`, I've got a type `A`, defined something like so:

```
newtype A = A Int
```

There's then external package `X` (which I don't control, unlike `P` and `Q`), which has a class `C` and an instance:

```
instance C Int where ...
```

So `X` depends on `base`.

Note `P` doesn't depend on `X`.

Now there's a package `Q`, which has a type `B` like so:

```
newtype B = B A
```

I want the following:

```
instance C B where ...
```

One way of achieving this is just adding deriving newtype clauses like so:

```
newtype A = A Int deriving newtype C -- in package P
newtype B = B A deriving newtype C -- in package Q
```

But then package `P` must depend on package `X`, all because `Q` want to use it in a particular way.

This is what I've been doing, but I feel like my codebase is becoming a bit of a blob. As in everything depends on everything. In somecases I've just been eliminating the newtype `B` entirely. But I think what is happening is my abstract utility code is becoming increasingly coupled with particular business logic, and I don't think this is a good thing.

I guess there's this approach also:

```
newtype B = B Int deriving newtype C -- in package Q
```

But then if the implementation of `A` changes, say like so:

```
newtype A = A Integer -- in package P
```

Then I've broken my code, as presumably what I'd now be doing to create an `A` is unwrapping `B` and wrapping it up in `A`.

I guess I could do this:

```
type A' = Int
newtype A = A A' -- in package P
newtype B = B A' deriving newtype C -- in package Q
```

But now things are getting a bit convoluted.

So I'm looking for alternatives to decouple `P` and `Q`, and in particular, not require `P` to depend on `X` (the package that defines `C`).

I'd like something like:

```
deriving newtype recursively C
```

Which pokes down unwrapping newtypes until it finds one that implements `C`, but I'm not sure it exists, and it probably isn't a good idea in the general case anyway (one sometimes newtypes to particularly hide certain instances that don't make sense, one does not want `Num` defined on timestamps, even if they are integers underneath).

So here I'm a bit stuck, and not sure the best way forward. Just looking for some options because this seems like a situation others would have encountered also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use the `DerivingVia` extension to write:

```
newtype B = B A deriving C via Int
```

That is, the contents of your modules can be:

```
-- X.hs
module X where

class C a where
  c :: a -> String

instance C Int where
  c _ = "Int"

-- P.hs
module P where

newtype A = A Int

-- Q.hs
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}

module Q where

import X
import P

newtype B = B A deriving C via Int

main = print $ c (B (A 10))
```

where Q depends on X and P, but P need not depend on X.

If the representation of `A` changes, this will result in a compile time error which will require you to update the `via` clause, but I'm not sure how you could change the underlying representation of `A` and not expect to have to fix some usages of `B` in module Q.

Comment: Yep, this is what I went with in the end. I suddenly remembered that `deriving via` is just a generalisation of `deriving newtype`. 

Only thing I added was a type family called `UnderlyingType` so then I can go:

`type UnderlyingType A = Int`
`data B = B A deriving C via UnderlyingType B`

Which means, if I follow this pattern, changes in A will automatically propagate into B.